# Cut a hole in a layout or dynamically occlude part of a view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-animation

[image]

*When the activity starts, the user should see the left side*

- i.e. the top green view is cropped such that only its bottom part is visible
- and the red views below are visible in an interactive way such that the user can press the red button for instance
- and any touch events registered with the top part of the green view should not work (on top of the top part not being visible)

*When the user touches the bottom part of the green view then the whole green view should become visible*

- now why cant I just set a top margin for the green view for instance (similar to how this image was produced) - the reason is that the green view is special in the sense that it contains gesture detection and responds to these gestures in a manner that is highly dependent on its full size - so i cannot resize the green view while i still need to make a part of it invisible (before the user touches the bottom part)

*Any suggestions?*

### XML for Right Side, How to Get Left Side Without Resizing Green View

*Green view is not actually a TextView, but a custom viewgroup with gesture-driven animations of its appearance*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/border_red">
            <Button
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_red"
                    android:text="View Below Visible"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="260dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
                android:text="View with Special Gesturing"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Judging by those images, can't you simply add the red view on top of the green view(which will still be full screen) with a height calculated in such way that it will leave enough space to show the desired bottom part of the green view?

Comment: @Luksprog great simple idea, but unfortunately it wont work, because i also have a background set for the root layout, which covers the whole screen and needs to shine through wherever you see black in the image - and if i just put the red view in front of the green view the background will not be visible because it will always be the bottom view in terms of z-order (below the green view)

Comment: How about using the above idea and simply create a "slice" of the normal background just to be used as the background for the red view(and the root will be just a container in this case), my guess is that you need the background only for the red view's part as the green fills all the screen(?!?). This working depends on what is that background, how big etc.

Comment: @Luksprog thats a possible solution but the background itself changes and in fact there are many red views behind the green view, so not an ideal solution - will try it if noone suggests a solution that burdens the other views less.. thanks for the solution though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the green view in a LinearLayout with a weighted transparent view above it. Something like:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"/>
        <WhateverCustomViewGroup
            android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
            android:text="View with Special Gesturing"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Attach the gesture detector to the LinearLayout instead of the green view, so it can still respond when collapsed. To expand, just `setVisibility(GONE)` on the empty view, and the green view will expand to its full size.

Comment: i think this may work, but had a look at the custom viewgroup im trying to work with specifically and on top of the touch listener [it seems to rely on the size of the custom view itself](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/blob/master/src/fi/harism/curl/CurlView.java) - any chance you have a cure for that? - it will otherwise take me awhile to understand how this curl viewgroup is set up (especially as it uses opengl)..

Comment: Interesting. So, when a user does a curl gesture while the green view is collapsed, what exactly should happen? I see what you're saying about the view's size playing a big part here, but I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish with a banner-sized page curler.

Comment: the moment the user touches the banner-sized page curler i will take a snapshot of the red views and set that as the page for the green view (which will look red actually) - basically im trying to employ this particular curler to work with the red views rather than a static bitmap and unfortunately the curler is not a viewgroup i can just add children to..